# tqdm progress meter not staying in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I just tried a simple tqdm example in python3. It works great but my problem is the "output format". The progress bar looks weird like this:

[image]

I need the output something like this in a single line

[image]

here is my code:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: this snippet works fine using ipython over terminator terminal emulator. your problem usually appears when you resize the terminal window during the execution.